# Using variable as object names in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to use a dynamic name for a property of an object.

For example, in the function below, I want to use the value of variable 'catagoryId' to get the child that results into the value for the variable catagoryId. For example if catagoryId = book. I want the last line to resolve to "endAtObject.orderValues.book".

```
        export const feedFetch = (catagoryId, endAtObject) => {
        endAtObject.orderValues.<<<catagoryId>>> 
        }
```

How do I do this? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: unless I'm missing something, this is plain JS: `endAtObject.orderValues[categoryId]`

Comment: If I do that I am getting an unexpected token error. Basically my endAtObject object has a child named orderValue and that has different childs with different names. In the example I am trying to get to a child named book.

Comment: drewmoore's comment is the correct way of doing it. Just make sure that order values is an Object, not a JSON string or array etc

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is 'computed property names'. This will do the job.

```
export const feedFetch = (catagoryId, endAtObject) => {
    endAtObject.orderValues[catagoryId]
}
```

You can find more info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer (CMD+F "Computed property names")